# unable to set forwarding in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a slight problem with forwarding using Struts. 
Now when users accessing my page like this -> `http://mypage/` 
they are automatically forwarded to /index.jsp.

But I'd also like to have index.jsp to be linked to name "sg".

So when they access page like this :
**`http://mypage/`**  > they will be forwarded to **`http://mypage/sg`** 
which is **`http://mypage/index.jsp`**.

As I've already mentioned above I'm using Struts to handle all these action. The below example is what I have in my struts.xml file. But it's working rather partially. When I access the page as stated above I'm getting redirected to **`http://mypage/sg`** and it also gives me **404 - Not Found**.

However when I try manually accessing the url (`http://mypage/sg`), it works perfectly.

```
 <package name="index" namespace="/" extends="default">
        <action name="">
            <result>/sg</result>
        </action>
        <action name="/sg">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I access the page as stated above I'm getting redirected to http://mypage.com/sg and it also gives me 404 - Not Found.

Answer :

If you want to call another action as result of one action then you need to mention attribute `type` of `result` tag

```
<action name="">
     <result type="redirect">/sg</result>
</action>
```

This will redirect to action `sg`.

### The redirect result type:

The redirect result type calls the standard `response.sendRedirect()` method, causing the browser to create a new request to the given location.

Comment: There is one more issue related to this. I have couple of links on this page 
 <a href="?pg=4">Stats</a> <a href="?pg=3">Contacts</a>  and so on..
Now since I'm accessing the index.jsp through the "sg" tag , I get the below error in my console. 

`Unexpected Exception caught setting 'pg' on 'class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport: Error setting expression 'pg' with value ['2', ]`

Everything is working though. It's just the error that keeps repeating in the console log.

Comment: @Wracker : You are trying to set `pg` when `sg` action called. This is different issue. Need to look your action class.

Comment: yes the "sg" represents the index.jsp and the "pg" is just an parameter that hold the page number. So when I want to display Contacts on my page the url would look like this `"http://mypage/sg?pg=3"`

Comment: Note that if you're redirecting to an action it's cleaner to use `redirectAction`.